Goldstein's "Classical Mechanics", Chapter 1, 16th question
Consider the following question from Goldstein's "Classical Mechanics".

$7.$ A particle moves in a plane under the influence of a force, acting toward a center of force, whose magnitude is
\begin{equation}
F = \frac{1}{r^2} \left(1- \frac{\dot{r}^2 - 2 \ddot{r}r}{c^2}\right)
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{r}$ is the distance of the particle to the center of force. 

$(\text{a})$ What is the expression for the generalized force here? 
$(\text{b})$ Find the generalized potential that will result in such a force. 
$(\text{c})$ From that form the Lagrangian for the motion in a plane. 
The force here represents the force between two charges in motion.

In this question, I used Lagrangian equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}\dot{r}}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}r}=F.$$
I used $F$ as that given in the question, but the first part confused me. Is the $F$ given in the question different from generalized force?

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you understood generalized forces as explained in the book? If not, please explain and type out the relevant paragraphs of the book in the question.
